# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Requested mail action not taken: mailbox unavailable'

Tags: system.net.mail, yahoo-mail

I am getting this message since Yahoo have made changes in user authentication. 
My code still works if I use option suggested by Yahoo, which is:

> While you switch apps or **update your app**, you can give the old app
>   temporary access. Just remember, this is not intended for permanent
>   access and you'll want to turn it off afterwards. Turn on Allow apps
>   that use less secure sign in. Once the feature is turned on, you'll
>   get regular alerts reminding you to turn it off...

My question is how to update my code to work  without turning on

> Allow apps that use less secure sign in.

On Yahoo side?

Code:

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("userid@yahoo.com", "user@example.com", "Test", "Hello World");

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; 
    smtp.Port = 587;//I tried 465 as well
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( "userid@yahoo.com", "myPassword");

    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using that option you would need to use [OAuth2](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/) for authentication instead of a user ID and password.

You would need to [register your application with Yahoo](https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/). Then go through the OAuth2 workflow:

- Get a request token from Yahoo
- Launch a Web browser and send the user to Yahoo to authorize your application and get an authorization key
- Trade the authorization key for an access token
- Store the access token somewhere and use it when logging in with SMTP

You're going to want third-party libraries for this. I don't think SmtpClient supports OAuth, and you'll want a library to handle the other OAuth details for you.

[Here](https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.OAuth.html) is an example of how to the OAuth this with MailBee.Net (a commercial e-mail library).